# Cannot bind C-c key in tmux

Tags: configuration, tmux

Does someone know the reason why in the tmux configuration

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-b
bind-key a send-prefix
bind-key C-c new-window
bind-key C-n next-window
bind-key C-p previous-window
bind-key C-a last-window
new-session -n $HOSTNAME
```

the mapping C-a works, but not the mapping C-c, C-n and C-p?

Answer (score 0):

Note that those bindings are for prefix **plus** sequence, so you've successfully bound `C-a C-c`, `C-a C-c`, etc. If you're looking to use *just* `C-c`, you want to use the `-n` ("no prefix") arg to `bind-key`:

```
bind-key -n C-c new-window
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was that there is a tmux server that needs to be stopped in order for the configuration changes to become effective. I wasn't aware of this.